# Protect appsettings.json in net core

Tags: security, .net-core, connection-string, appsettings, mail-server

My project consists of: angular frontend, net core backend and mysql db.

Only the db will be put on the server, instead I will distribute the frontend (dist folder to run with http-server) and backend (bin folder with executable inside) to various users who will run them locally by connecting to the common database.

At the moment I put the connection string to the db in appsettings.json in the backend, as well as the information of the account used as a sender in an email service.

In this way the data in question would be viewable in plain text by all users to whom I will pass the backend. What is the best solution to fix this?

Comment: add hideable values directly to code, on compiled it will be in DLL ,still can be viewed but not with text editor

Comment: could you give me some more tips?